# How to escape a string that looks like a regular expression in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, escaping

I have a script that, among other things, searches a list of text files to replace a Windows path (text string) with another path.

The problem is that some of the folder names begin with a number and a dash. Perl seems to think that I am trying to invoke a regular expression here. I get the message, "Reference to nonexistent group in regex".

the string looks like this:

```
\\\BAGlobal\6-Engineering\3-Tech
```

I have quoted it like this:

```
 my $find = "\\\\\\\BAGlobal\\\6-Engineering\\\3-Tech"
```

How do I escape the `6-`  and `3-`  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The problem is not the the dash in `6-` but all the backslashes `\`.**

It thinks that `\3` and `\6` are back-references to previously matched groups, like `/foo(bar) foo\1/` would match the string `foobar foobar`.

If you use this in a pattern match you need to either include `\Q` and `\E` to add quoting, or apply the [`quotemeta` built-in](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) to your `$find`.

```
my $find = '\\\\\\\BAGlobal\\\6-Engineering\\\3-Tech';

$string =~ m/\Q$find\E/;
```

Or with `quotemeta`.

```
my $find = quotemeta '\\\\\\\BAGlobal\\\6-Engineering\\\3-Tech';

$string =~ m/$find/;
```

Also see [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quoting-metacharacters).

Note that your example code is probably wrong. The number of backslashes you have there is uneven, and double quotes `""` interpolate, so each pair of backslashes `\\` turn into one actual backslash in the string. But because you have 7 of them, the last one is seen as the escape for `B`, turning that into `\B`, which is not a valid escape sequence. I used single quotes `''` in my code above.

Comment: I'd also use single quotes for readability, as double quotes aren't necessary.

Comment: @choroba Actually the double-quotes `""` change the meaning of the string. The number of backslashes ``\`` is odd, so the double-quoted string tries to interpolate `\B`, which then breaks. Try `say "\\\\\\\BAGlobal\\\6-Engineering\\\3-Tech"; say '\\\\\\\BAGlobal\\\6-Engineering\\\3-Tech';`.

Comment: Note that `\B` is valid in a regex, though, as the negation of `\b`.

Comment: @choroba but that's `q{\B}`, not `qq{\B}`. In my above code we have the first one after I changed the quotes, which would turn into the character-class, but then there is `quotemeta` to make sure it doesn't.

Comment: With quotemeta, do I still want to escape my original back slashes? Or, does quotemeta do it for me?

Comment: @SKing: TITS = "Try it to see"

Comment: @sk because you didn't indent your question properly and tried to make it look good. But when we fixed the markdown in your question that ended up as content. That's why it is important to be precise and use proper syntax for the question. Quotemeta will work anyway. Just try.

Comment: this is working now. I used quotemeta , single quotes, and no extra back slashes.

Comment: Thank you both for your help